# How to continue for loop even after an error is thrown in Databricks?

Tags: azure, for-loop, pyspark, databricks

I have a `ADLS Storage container` in `Azure` which has 10000+ files in `JSON` format (very complex `JSON` structure). I am extracting some specific fields from each `JSON` file and converting them to csv using `Databricks`. I am using `for loop` to go through each file 1 by 1 inside the container and store the fields in a dataframe. After the `for` `loop` finishes I `write` the dataframe to a different container as a `csv` file with the required fields. My problem is some `JSON` files do not have the field which I require and it throws an error and stops the `for loop`.
What I want to achieve is, if the field that I am looking for is not present inside the `json` file, the file should be skipped and we should move to the next file without throwing an error and stopping the `for loop`.

My code is:

```
path = "/dbfs/mnt/...path"
path1 = "/mnt/...path"
for fname in os.listdir(path):
    df = spark.read.option("multiLine", "true).json(path1 + fname)
    at_name = df.select(explode(df.attributes.name)).collect()[0][0]
    at_def = df.select(explode(df.definitions.attributeDefinition)).collect()[0][0]
    ### appending to the main dataframe which later gets converted to csv here##
```

Now if the field is not present which I want to extract, the code stops because it throws the error of `field not found`. How should I modify my `for loop`?

Comment: why not simply read the whole directory at once?

Comment: @AlexOtt +1. Spark is designed exactly for these use cases, you don't need a for loop. You should also post the code you use for extracting the field, otherwise it's hard to find the issue

Comment: @GustavoPuma I have added the code where I select the field. The reason why I am going through each file 1 by 1 is that every file has a different schema, hence my error that not all files have the field which I want to extract, like there are some json files which don't have definitions.attributeDefintion attribute in them and it throws the error and stops my for loop.

Comment: have you try wrapping your spark read piece inside for loop with `try except`, so whatever happened and throwing errors, your code still run?

Comment: still would be worth a try. spark can create a composite, "super" schema out of files with differing schemas, if you read them in one go. You could also try defining such composite schema yourself manually if you don't have too many fields